# Why does Arduino mega and SIM900 won't send message if I input/read to serial monitor, different phone numbers?

Tags: arduino, sms, gsm, sim900

I am new to arduino and gsm sim900, and I currently working with the project when student scan their barcode it will input attendance to database and send sms to their guardians. My issue is when I try to input different numbers like "serial.available" and "readString(phonenumber)" it wont send a message, I get no errors and the sim have e-load/. Sorry for bad grammar. Here is the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(6,7);
String number;
void setup()
{
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println ("SIM900A Ready");
  delay(100);
 Serial.print("Enter PHONE NUMBER: ");
 while(Serial.available()==0){}          //INPUT PHONE NUMBER
 number = Serial.readString();
 delay(500);
  Serial.println ("Type s to send message or r to receive message");

}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 's':
      SendMessage();
      break;
    case 'r':
      RecieveMessage();
      break;
  }
 if (SIM900A.available()>0)
   Serial.write(SIM900A.read());
}
 void SendMessage()
{
  Serial.println ("Sending Message");
  SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Set SMS Number");
  SIM900A.print("AT+CMGS=\""+number+"\"\r");   //send to input phone number
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(number);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println ("Set SMS Content");
  SIM900A.print("Message from ArduinoGSMSIM900");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println ("Finish");
  SIM900A.println((char)26);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Message has been sent");
}
 void RecieveMessage()
{
  Serial.println ("SIM900A Membaca SMS");
  delay (1000);
  SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write ("Unread Message done");
}
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after so many research I solved my problem. This is for people who will have the same issue as mine that wasted a lot of time for a simple line of code. 
When I `serial.readString()` the output will have a white space like @hcheung said, so to get rid of that white space I use `number.Trim()`, it will read the string in exact length.

Final sketch for arduino GSM SIM900:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(10,11);
String number;
String message;
void setup()
{
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println ("SIM900A Ready");
  delay(100);
 Serial.print("Enter PHONE NUMBER: ");
 while(Serial.available()==0){}
 number = Serial.readString();
 delay(100);
 number.trim();
 delay(200);
 Serial.println(number.length());
 Serial.print("Enter MESSAGE: ");
 while(Serial.available()==0){}
 message = Serial.readString();
 delay(100);
  Serial.println ("Type s to send message or r to receive message");

}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 's':
      SendMessage();
      break;
    case 'r':
      RecieveMessage();
      break;
  }
 if (SIM900A.available()>0)
   Serial.write(SIM900A.read());
}
 void SendMessage()
{
  Serial.println ("Sending Message");
  SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Set SMS Number");
  SIM900A.print("AT+CMGS=\""+number+"\"\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(number);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println ("Set SMS Content");
  SIM900A.print(message);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println ("Finish");
  SIM900A.println((char)26);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Message has been sent");
}
 void RecieveMessage()
{
  Serial.println ("SIM900A Membaca SMS");
  delay (1000);
  SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write ("Unread Message done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the SoftwareSerial Library [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial), you will noticed it said:

> The library has the following known limitations:
>
> Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 50, 51, 52, 53, A8 (62), A9 (63), A10 (64), A11 (65), A12 (66), A13 (67), A14 (68), A15 (69).

So change your line on `SoftwareSerial SIM900A(6,7);` to something else than pin 6 and 7.

Comment: thank you for reply. I tried all the pins and still not sending sms. though when I tried pin 10 and 11 it gives me an error like this

```AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT+CMGS="+639206188890
"


ERROR
message```

Btw I forgot to tell that I'm using a USB Host Shield

Comment: At least when you using pin 10 and 11, you be able to communicate and get feedback from SIM900 module. That was what your question about ("I got no error" as your said). If this help you, please accept the answer for the benefits of future readers.

Comment: Your got error now is a separate issue and related to your coding. for example, I noticed your phone number has a space at the end.

Comment: BTW, use `SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\""+number+"\"");` instead of `SIM900A.print()`, to make sure all the commands end with proper `\n\r`.